Italian.SE is graduating on December 16th!
Congratulations everyone: after much effort we are finally graduating!
The Community Managers have communicated us that, based on the longevity, number and quality of questions and other parameters, Italian.SE will graduate from beta on December 16th 2021.
What does it mean for us? Not much. The most visible difference will be the loss of the "beta" label on the website banner. Some moderation instruments (e.g. migration paths) will become available as well. In the future some graphic customization might become possible, but for now we will keep the present theme.
Probably the most notable change will be the Moderators Elections: the moderating team will not be appointed by SE anymore, but will be elected by the community (yeah, this means you!). All current moderators will be automatically candidates, but users can also nominate alternate candidates (and/or self-nominate). Don't hold your breath though - due to the great number of sites graduating at the same time the elections will be held sometime in 2022 or even 2023, depending on how the scheduling will work. We will keep you posted as soon as we learn more details.
I would like to take a few lines to thank my fellow pro-tempore moderators, egreg and Charo, and all the people that served as moderators in the past. Even if their work is not always visible, it is essential for the working of this site. A big thank you to all the members of the Community Team as well, past and present, that offered support and guidance when it proved necessary to take difficult decisions.
Last, but most certainly not least, a huge thank you to all our users. Without you all asking and answering questions, flagging and editing posts, this website couldn't exist.

Congratulazioni a tutti: dopo molti sforzi finalmente saremo promossi!
I Community Manager ci hanno comunicato che, sulla base della longevità, del numero e della qualità delle domande e altri parametry, Italian.SE verrà promosso da beta il 16 dicembre 2021.
Cosa significa questo per noi? Non molto. La differenza più visibile sarà la perdita della descrizione "beta" sul banner del sito. Alcuni strumenti di moderazione (e.g. i percorsi di migrazione) diventeranno altresì disponibile. Nel futuro potrebbero diventare possible alcune personalizzazioni grafiche, ma per il momento terremo il tema attuale.
Probabilmente il cambio più importante saranno le elezioni dei moderatori: la squadra di moderatori non sarà più nominata da SE, ma sarà eletta dalla comunità (sì, questo significa voi!). Tutti i moderatori correnti saranno automaticamente candidati, ma gli utenti possono nominare candidati alternativi (e/o autonominarsi). Non abbiate fretta però - a causa del gran numero di siti promossi allo stesso tempo, le elezioni avranno luogo a qualche punto del 2022 o persino del 2023, a seconda di come verrà effettuata la programmazione. Vi terremo aggiornati non appena sapremo ulteriori dettagli.
Vorrei spendere un po' di parole per ringraziare i miei compagni moderatori pro-tempore, egreg e Charo, e tutte le persone che hanno servito come moderatori in passato. Anche se il loro lavoro non è sempre visibile, è essenziale per il funzionamento di questo sito. Un grosso grazie anche a tutti i membri del Community Team, passati e presenti, che hanno offerto supporto e guida quando è stato necessario prendere decisioni difficili.
Ultimo, ma certo non per importanza, un enorme grazie a tutti i nostri utenti. Senza tutti voi, che chiedete e rispondete a domande, che segnalate e correggete post, questo sito non potrebbe esistere.

Congratulazioni!

@Rosie Grazie! :)

Now, we are no longer Beta! See the official announcement. Congratulations to everyone in this community!

Yay!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
